# React setState callback function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I made a custom FormContext in React and I'd like to add a feature like the valueChange observable in Angular. I was thinking about adding a method in the context that receive a callback and sets it the state, and then add a use effect that fire the callback every time the form is changed. This is what I've done so far:

```
const [controls, setControls] = useState<GenericObject<FormControl>>({});
const [callback, setCallback] = useState<(() => void) | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!callback) return;
    callback();
  }, [controls]);

  const buildForm = (_controls: GenericObject<FormControl>) => {
    setControls(_controls);
  };

  const onValueChange = (_callback: () => void) => {
    setCallback(() => _callback);
  };

  const values = (): GenericObject => {
    return Object.entries(controls).reduce((acc, [key, control]) => {
      acc[key] = control.value;
      return acc;
    }, {} as GenericObject);
  };

// other methods
```

And from my component I call the onValueChange function like that:

```
const {buildForm, onValueChange, values} = useForm()

useEffect(() => {
  buildForm({ // controls })
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  onValueChange(myCallback)
}, [])

const myCallback = () => {
  console.log(values())
}
```

and it works, every time I update the form controls the callbacked is called. The problem is that what values() returns is an empty object, whether in other parts of the code is populated correctly with the key-values of the form controls.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Every state change causes a rerender of a component. All the variables are restored from hooks, but the scope of the component function is different every time. Now take a look at the very first render. `useForm` hook returns 3 variables, `myCallback` function is created and linked with `values` by closure, and this callback is passed to `onValueChange` via useEffect on the first render only. So, this funcion exists and sees variables from this exact scope. So due to closure your function only sees value from scope it was attached, it does not sees any other values from next rerenders.

Comment: The entire concept is very...not React-y? The implementation you are using is appropriate for an [actor-based model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#:~:text=An%20actor%20is%20a%20computational,the%20next%20message%20it%20receives.) where entities communicate by passing messages. React is a reactive model where views are a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) of application state, and having that sort of "event listener" type code is very much a code smell. I don't know Angular but given that you mentioned it's an rxjs observable then a callback...

Comment: ...doesn't capture the semantics of that either: an Observable is a *value* that's a first-class entity in the system, not just a pubsub callback registration mechanism.

Comment: I understand what both of you are saying. I suspected it wasn't the best idea when I started coding it, but I tried anyway. Is there a more react way to do what I need or am I looking at the problem from the wrong angle?

Comment: @carloberd hey don't forget to @ people specifically otherwise we don't necessarily see your comments. As for your question, it depends on whether you want to update the application state or perform a side-effect. If it's the first one pass a callback down to the form that updates the parent (or grandparent, or...) component state. If it's for a side effect, put it in a useEffect hook with the value from the form as a dependency in the array and it will re-run every time that value changes.